# prependTo item only once on div

Tags: jquery, prepend

Let's say I have this data and I just want to `prependTo` only once, because when I tried to `prependTo` the `$('.entry-title')` to `('.container)` it display twice every article.

```
<article class="blogpage-posts">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">Data One</a>
    <h1 class="entry-title">Data to Prepend One</h1>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="blogpage-posts">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">Data Two</a>
    <h1 class="entry-title">Data to Prepend Two</h1>
  </div>
</article>
```

This is the code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.entry-title').prependTo('.container');
});
```

This is the result when using that code.

```
Data to Prepend One
Data to Prepend Two <--- the data the display twice
Data One

Data to Prepend Two
Data to Prepend One <--- the data the display twice
Data One Two
```

Comment: `$('.entry-title').each((i, el) => $(el).prependTo($(el).closest('.container')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.entry-title').each(function(){
        $(this).prependTo($(this).closest('.container'));
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="blogpage-posts">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">Data One</a>
    <h1 class="entry-title">Data to Prepend One</h1>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="blogpage-posts">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">Data Two</a>
    <h1 class="entry-title">Data to Prepend Two</h1>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: I already try that one, it will not display twice but all the `.entry-title` will go to  top it should be each `.entry-title` is above and below are `a`

Comment: I just modified it. I had realized that it was wrong - and I think this won't work either.

Comment: @dextree mate if it helped you, you can mark it as an answer. It may turn out to be helpful for someone else looking for a similar solution.